# How to use the JavaScript Enhancement plugin in Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I installed JavaScript Enhancement through Package Control.

Does it need to be activated first from somewhere before being able to use it?

Comment: I have the same issue. Doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, no need to activate anything.

Just create a new JavaScript file and you'll notice its features are working.

Make sure your file is treated as JavaScript. You can check by looking at the bottom right corner. "JavaScript" should be selected.

Comment: But in the right corner is still javascript written. Do i need to disable it?if yes , how could i achieve it?

Comment: I have selected Javascript (Babel)..Will it still work?

Comment: I have JavaScript selected but it doesn't seem to work. The autocomplete I get is not related to an object at all rather it shows list of variables on file in no particular order.

Comment: @Michael have you installed the JavaScript Enhancements plugin?

Comment: @MoustafaEl-Sayed Yes I installed the JavaScript Enhancement plugin. I was struggling with it and that's how I got to this page while searching for solution. Turns out I wasn't quite successful so I quit.

Answer (score 0):

I also could not get auto completion suggestion or any pop up while typing in sublime. I have tried several pluggins: `all autocompletion, javascript enhancement`. But nothing worked. So after reading some answer, I installed `sublimeCodeIntel`. I don't know why but only this plugging can give me the autocompletion popup.

So you can give it a try.